# Extracting child attributes from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This is my XML.

```
<Contents>
  <Name>euwe</Name>
  <Data>
    <Key>45656858</Key>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Key>675478</Key>
  </Data>
  ...
</Contents>
```

I need to find all the `Key` values. Here is what I'm trying.

```
string xml = "..."; // above xml
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList xnl = doc.SelectNodes("Data");
Console.WriteLine(xnl.Count);
foreach (XmlNode node in xnl) 
{
    //Console.WriteLine(node);
}
```

But the count is zero.

Comment: try this line: `var xnl = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Data");`

Comment: There are many options for using C# to navigate an XML document. See marked duplicates for examples of each, including serialization, XPath, LINQ, and `XmlDocument` (which you're using here). If after reviewing the various examples that answer your basic question you have some _specific_ problem you can't figure out, post a new question with a good [mcve] and a detailed explanation of what that _specific_ problem is. Be sure to explain what you've done so far to debug the problem, and what _specifically_ is still causing you trouble.